Can ようにする nuance be used with other verbs other than する?
肩をリラックスさせるように上下させて吐息を吐き出す。
I found this description in a book. My first impression was to read it as "As if"
His shoulder went up and down as if trying to relax and left out a sight.
However, can ように here have the same nuance as ようにする  using another verb?

ように used to indicate a purpose does not necessarily have to be paired with する. In general, ように means either "so that; in order to" or "as if; like" depending on the context. For example, 彼が分かるように話す means "to speak so that he understands", while 詩を読むように話す means "to speak as if reading poetry".

肩をリラックスさせるように上下させて吐息を吐き出す。

This case is somewhat ambiguous. If "relaxing" is the intended purpose of the shoulder movement, it means "so that". This interpretation is especially correct when the implied subject is the speaker themselves.
If "relaxing" is merely the speaker's subjective interpretation of someone else's shoulder movement, it can mean "as if". However, without context, I think this interpretation is less likely.
